# Use grand central dispatch to call block when variable is set?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

I needed to call a method once a Boolean was set to NO. The Boolean is set to YES when the animation starts and when it finishes it sets to NO.

A user presses a button to call the block, they can press the button while the animation is occurring or when it isn't. But the block should wait until the animation is complete.

Is it ok to use a while loop and grand central dispatch to achieve this or is there a better way (ie doesn't use an empty while loop or a preexisting way)

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,0);
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    while ([self isAnimating]) {}
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self doSomething];
    });
});
```

The `doSomething` method contains calls to UIKit methods which is why I've the the second `dispatch_async` function to execute it on the main thread.

EDIT: Forgot to say the initial animation is not something I have access to (it is written by Apple)

Comment: Why not just refactor your code so that you receive a callback after the animation finishes?

Comment: @sudorm-rf, because the user can press the button without the animation ever happening. So if the animation is not happening the `doSomething` should be called immediately.

Comment: Okay, well if you can't use callbacks and can't use KVO, why not just create a timer that polls a method that checks the status of this boolean?  In that way even if it's not animating, `doSomething` would be called immediately.  From within the polling method you should of course invalidate the timer if you don't need it any more.  That is, unless I completely misunderstood your problem.

Comment: @sudorm-rf, I hadn't thought of that, won't that be more inefficient than this though?

Comment: I have no statistics to back me up, but I do know that `NSTimer`s are very lightweight.  I'm almost positive that polling a method would be much better (and less resource-intensive) than running an empty `while` loop.

Comment: How does the boolean get set to NO?  Does it happen in some block or callback that you wrote?  Or does it happen in library code that you can't change?

Comment: Is it the `isAnimating` property of a `UIImageView`?  If not, what exactly is it?

Answer (score 4):

You could use the new `UIView` block animation APIs. Such as:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
    // Animation here
} completion:^(BOOL b){
    // Completion here
}];
```

Or if the animation is of unknown duration consider using a `@property` for the `BOOL` and using Key-Value Observing.

**Edit:**

I think `sudo rm -rf` `NSTimer` might be the easiest for you to implement. While you could use KVO it's not the easiest to get started with and timers are easy. Here is a basic example of how you could implement a timer conditionally depending on the need for it.

```
-(void)doSomethingTimerTarget:(NSTimer *)timer{
    if ([self isAnimating]) return;
    else {
        [timer invalidate];
        [self doSomething:nil];
    }
}
-(IBAction)doSomething:(id)sender{
    if (sender && [self isAnimating]){ // if sender is nil then `doSomethingTimerTarget:` called the method no need to check again
        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.05 target:self selector:@selector(doSomethingTimerTarget:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"actually doing something");
        // Actually do something here
    }
}
```

One of the things you might want to add first is to disable the button when it's pushed and has to wait to execute, to prevent multiple requests.

**Edit:** Response to:"KVO would be better but how could I prevent it from happening when the user hasnt pressed the button, and the animation completes, use another BOOL like `pressedButton`"

To start, yes a simple `BOOL` would work. But remember you don't have to key-value observe full time. In the timer code example above where the timer is instantiated replace that with a call to `addObserver:..`, then in the callback remove the observer. In this way you are only observing when it matters, you wouldn't need to maintain a separate `BOOL`. Here is an untested mock-up:

```
-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context{
    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:/*YourKeypath*/] && ![self isAnimating]){
        [self removeObserver:self forKeyPath:/*YourKeypath*/];
        [self doSomething:nil];
    }
}
-(IBAction)doSomething:(id)sender{
    if (sender && [self isAnimating]){ // if sender is nil then the observe method called this method no need to check `isAnimating` again
        [self addObserver:self forKeyPath:/*YourKeypath*/...//etc
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"actually doing something");
        // Actually do something here
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for KVO suggestion. That is, assuming the view animations won't work for your case.

Comment: I have edited my question, also using KVO would be the same as implementing a call back, but if the animation never happens the observer will never be called and the `doSomething` method will never be called.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just check `isAnimating` at the beginning of your `IBAction` method and call `doSomething` if it's not animating OR begin observing if it is.

Comment: Yep your edit was along the lines of what I was thinking.  Thanks for putting it into code.

Comment: I forgot I could also just have an if statement when setting the timer (duh!), KVO would be better but how could I prevent it from happening when the user hasnt pressed the button, and the animation completes, use another BOOL like `pressedButton`?

Comment: Edited in response to comment.